# TrueCrypt vs BitLocker + EFS proper usage

Tags: windows, truecrypt, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I need to protect sensitive data on my computers both at home & office.

Home: Win 7 Ultimate, shared with others, I'm the only admin. Many people boot it.

Work: Windows XP Pro under domain, dedicated to me (notice the domain!) I'm a member of administrators. I'm the only person that boot it.

Probably I don't have any TPM modules.

Since I'm new to disk encryption, here are my scenarios:

**Home:** Use BitLocker on all volumes. Then encrypt sensitive folders (EFS) and restrict permissions. Do not forget to dump/save/password-protect any keys/certificates/etc for future use. Other people may still boot & use their own accounts.

**Work:** Use TrueCrypt to encrypt all volumes. Make rescue CD. Encrypt sensitive folders (EFS) and restrict permissions. Remove default admin shares to limit data access from network against other administrators.

You can use my PCs or remove my disks. Now anyone think that s/he can still access my data without password?

*P.S: I assume that you are not NSA.*

Comment: When dealing with security, you are allowed to assume nothing. :P It's also generally considered that for anyone trying to get at your data, if they can touch the system then the game is over and they've won.

Comment: Did you set both computers to lock after 5/10 Min of inactivity?

Comment: Yes. And I usually lock my desktop when I leave. TrueCrypt with strong password (20 chars) seems OK at work. At boot time it asks for password. At home it's not an option, others would boot the PC without my password.